# How to fix missing file in visual studio cordova blank new app project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova

I am having a problem with my codova plugin and I can't really run anything or write code.
What happens:

1. None of the additional files are shown in the solution explorer when I open a new cordova project. (There should be several files and folders according to the manual.) -- see picture included.
2. I can not build/run (probably because of 1).

[image]

I am using Visual Studio enterprise 2015 with the latest updates.
I tried going through the manuals and re-installed twice, nothing helped.

Please help :)

Thanks,Isan.

Comment: Are the files still in the physical folder(only not included into the project)?  Are you getting any missing file error while creating new blank project?

Comment: I know this is an older question, but has there been a resolution to this issue, and if so, what was it?

Comment: At the end my issue was that I had to update to the latest enterprise version. So when I found the serial key I was given from my university and used it to sign in, then i could update VS and then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Open developer command prompt and run devenv /setup. See if it can help to fix the issue.

If above doesn't work, please

1. go to control panel-> Programs and Features -> double click to launch the installation program of Visual Studio 2015.
2. Then select "Modify" and deselect the tools for Apache Cordova to remove it first.
3. After #2, repeat #1 & #2 but this time please select the tools for apache Cordova to reinstall it.